# If FileUpload is empty, then keep the existing picture from database c#

Tags: c#, image, file-upload

I have a page where I need to edit existing blog post that has a picture. I need to edit only the text in blog post. But if I just jump over the file uploader and do not choose any picture, then I just don't get any picture at the edited post and get NULL value in database.

How do I edit the post and keep the existing picture in database without overwriting it with an empty one?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you handle the file-choser result?

Comment: please show the relevant code, we are not magicians